# Merging write protected pdfs using itextsharp

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext

I have written a program that allows me to merge as many sets of pdfs as I want together (in other words I have a bunch of cover page pdfs that I want to pair with another set of pdfs). It works fine until I try to merge a write protected pdf. I checked with the line "PdfEncryptor.IsPrintingAllowed() which return false.

I tried downloading a program built for this called PDFSam and it handled it fine.

The pdf is not password protected it is just write protected. Any idea how to get around this in vb.net

Comment: What do you mean by "write protected"?

Comment: PDFSam is a tool built on top of an old version of iText. Your PDF is protected with an owner password. PDFSam removes that protection. I'll close the question as a duplicate.